# Async Servlet request loadbalancer timeout

Tags: java, asynchronous, jersey, java-ee-6, servlet-3.0

I am using java async servlet for long running tasks that I am implementing using jersey deployed in weblogic.

```
   @GET
   @Path("/asyncjob")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public void asyncJob(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
      
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

      executor.execute(() -> {
           String result = longRunningTask();
           asyncResponse.resume(result);
      });
   }
```

I am calling the above rest api through an javascript AJAX call.

This is working fine in development environment. However I have been told,even if the task is processed asynchronously in weblogic in a separate thread, this will not work in actual production because the loadbalancer will timeout after the default timeout period, and will terminate the client connection.

We havent had a chance to test it in a production like environment yet. But from what I understand, once we start an async job, the main weblogic thread that handles the web request would return. Once the job is completed, a different thread would be used to commit the response and at this point it is a server push. So during this server push notification, is loadbalancer timeout still applicable?

If loadbalancer actually times out, then that defeats the purpose of async servlet, since it is not going to work for any real life production application. Is there a solution to get around the loadbalancer timeout problem? What alternatives do we have?

Answer (score 0):

async in this context is not really async from the client perspective. The client  (javascript) will be waiting for the response. Async servlets/JAX-RS is about keeping threads busy and don't having a thread blocked waiting for data to be writen.

For truly async communication with a javascript client you should look for SSE in JAX-RS or use WebSockets.

[Here is a nice introduction to SSE](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-jax-rs-sse)